# How to add custom metadata text box dropdown to sidebar in Gutenberg editor for all post types

Tags: custom-field, post-meta

I am looking for how to add a custom dropdown on the right sidebar of the Gutenberg editor. I would like to do this within the functions.php of my custom theme, not with a plugin. The dropdown would be similar to the "excerpt" dropdown, as it would just have a name and a text box. In the image below, I'd like to add the dropdown where the red pen is on the right.

[image: Example Image]

Is there a function and hook I can use in my functions.php to implement this? Thanks!

Comment: That is basically a JavaScript (JS) thing, so you'll need to have JS skills, and there is a [tutorial](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/tutorials/plugin-sidebar-0/) that you can try.

Answer (score 0):

The modern way to do is to use javascript, as Sally CJ noted in the comments.

But, you can get the job done by doing it the old with [add_meta_box()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_meta_box/). When registering a custom metabox you need to set the context argument to `side` to make the metabox appear on the block editor sidebar.

*See the [metabox documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/metadata/custom-meta-boxes/) for more details on how to add, render and save the custom metabox. You can also find plenty of metabox related examples here on WPSE.*